# How to define a multidimensional array in C++ with 'n' rows and 'm' columns and iterate values using For Loop?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17

I want a program that asks the number of rows and columns of the multidimensional array and then using For loop iterate values in the array.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, m, x;
    int a[n][m];
    cin>>n>>m;
    for(int i; i<n ; i++)
    {
        for(int j;  j<m ; j++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter the values";
            cin>>x;
            a[i][j] = x;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

here it gets error:

```
main.cpp|6|warning: 'm' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
main.cpp|6|warning: 'n' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
```

Comment: As it says m and n are not initialized, what would be the size of your array a? m and n can be anything. Just for learning purpose move your array declaration after cin and see.

Comment: Your use of `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;` indicates that your learning until now was based on competitive challenges, which are not meant to teach. Try your text book instead. It will tell you about things like `std::array` and `std::vector` and the possibility to nest them. If it is good material it will probably also tell you that VLAs (variable lenght arrays) are not part of the C++ language. Otherwise I recommend to learn reading error messages, as Aval also hints in their comment above.

Comment: `int n, m, x; int a[n][m];` -- Even if `n` and `m` are initialized, this is still not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a *compile-time* expression, not a runtime value.  Learn what `std::vector` is, and in your case `std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(n, std::vector<int>(m));`

Comment: Please read the mouseover help bubbles for the tags you used. They are at conflict, because as tagged you ask for solutions which do NOT contain any features introduced awith C++14 and at the same time use features of C++14 and beyond. Generally please take the [tour] and read [ask] and maybe https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't declare the array unknown size. You must do it dynamically.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 0, m = 0;

    //. Get the matrix's size
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Input the row count: "; cin >> n;
        cout << "Input the column count: "; cin >> m;

        if (n < 1 || m < 1)
        {
            cout << "Invalid values. Please retry." << endl;
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    //. Allocate multi-dimensional array dynamically.
    int ** mat = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = new int[m];
    }

    //. Receive the elements.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << "Input the element of (" << i + 1 << "," << j + 1 << "): ";
            cin >> mat[i][j];
        }
    }

    //. Print matrix.
    cout << endl << "Your matrix:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {       
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << mat[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << std::endl;
    }

    //. Free memories.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        delete[] mat[i];
    }
    delete[] mat;

    return 0;
}
```

If you like to use stl, it can be simple.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

using ROW = vector<int>;
using MATRIX = vector<ROW>;

int main()
{
    int n = 0, m = 0;
    MATRIX mat;

    cin >> n >> m;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        ROW row;
        row.resize(m);

        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cin >> row[j];
        }
        mat.push_back(row);
    }

    for (auto & row : mat)
    {
        for (auto & iter : row)
        {
            cout << iter << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some comments.

- Please never use `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. This is a none C++ compliant compiler extension
- Please do not use `using namespace std;`. Always use fully qualified names.
- For the above to statements you will find thousands of entries here on SO
- In C++ you cannot use VLAs, Variable Length Array, like `int a[n][m];`. This is not part of the C++ language
- You should not use C-Style arrays at all. Use `std::array` or, for your case `std::vector`.
- Use meaningful variable names
- Write comments
- Always initialize all variables, before using them!!!

And, last but not least. You will not learn C++ on this nonesens "competition - programming" sites.

And one of many millions possible C++ solutions (advanced) could look like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    
    // Read the dimension of the 3d data
    if (unsigned int numberOfRows{}, numberOfCoulmns{}; (std::cin >> numberOfRows >> numberOfCoulmns) and (numberOfRows > 0u) and (numberOfCoulmns > 0u)) {

        // Define a vector with the requested size
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> data(numberOfRows, std::vector<int>(numberOfCoulmns, 0));

        // Read all data
        std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [&](std::vector<int>& col) mutable
            { auto it = col.begin();  std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), numberOfCoulmns, it++); });

        // Show debug output
        std::for_each(data.begin(), data.end(), [](std::vector<int>& col)
            {std::copy(col.begin(), col.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t")); std::cout << '\n'; });

    }
    else std::cerr << "\nError: Invalid input given\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your response. But then how can I learn C++? Should I follow some well known text books?